# How to query all the dependencies in maven's private server?

Tags: java, maven

I only have the address of maven private server of the company. Can I traverse all modules in the private server? What should I do?

Comment: Why do you want to find _all_ the dependencies in your Maven server? What is this good for?

Answer (score 0):

You should add the address of your company's private repository in the repositories section of pom.xml for project specific search of dependencies or .m2/settings.xml for global level dependencies search.